# How to terminate a JFrame after a specific amount of time?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, gif

I want a JFrame to display a gif, which is my loading screen and then automatically terminate. I am OK with either terminating it after a particular time period or after it completes displaying the gif. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> to display a gif, which is my loading screen and then automatically terminate.

Sounds like you might want a splash screen.

See the section in the Swing tutorial on [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) for more information and a working example.

Comment: FYI: If it's an animated GIF the OP will need to setup their own repaint timer, but +1 for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `javax.swing.Timer` to call `dispose` on the frame to close it after...

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details